# How to implement google tag manager in ionic 6+ and capacitor 4+?

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

The task is to integrate GTM (Google Tag Manager) into the Ionic app. I already tried such plugins as cordova-google-tag-manager-plugin or so, but seems like they do not work or simply cannot be installed.

To clarify, I don't need to add Firebase Analytics only, there are new plugins for it. I need to integrate the whole GTM and seems like there is no proper plugin for the Ionic 6+/Capacitor yet. Could you please help?